# How do I get data to start entering in second listbox after first listbox has 7 numbers?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

So I've been working on this form where I have three different employees, and I'm supposed to be entering the units shipped for about 7 days(so there should be 7 numbers)
Now after I get all 7 numbers for the first listbox that I use I need it to start entering the data into the second textbox, get 7 numbers there and then move to the third textbox, I have no problem getting the numbers in the first textbox but I can't get it to switch to the second textbox after the numbers have been entered.

Any ideas?

```
Private Sub EnterButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EnterButton.Click
     Dim output As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(InputTextbox.Text, output) Then
            If InputTextbox.Text >= 0 AndAlso InputTextbox.Text <= 1000 Then
                Employee1.Add(InputTextbox.Text)
                EmployeeListbox1.DataSource = Nothing
                EmployeeListbox1.DataSource = Employee1
                InputTextbox.Clear()
            End If
        End If
```

This is my code^

So far I have tried storing the data in an array so

```
Dim students(6) As Integer

  students(0) = "" &inputtextbox.Text
  students(1) = "" &inputtextbox.Text
  students(2) = "" &inputtextbox.Text
  students(3) = "" &inputtextbox.Text
  students(4) = "" &inputtextbox.Text
  students(5) = "" &inputtextbox.Text
  students(6) = "" &inputtextbox.Text
```

Not even sure if thats right because I'm trying to grab the number from the textbox, anyway i tried that I also tried

```
        If Employee1.Count = 7 Then
        If InputTextbox.Text >= 0 AndAlso InputTextbox.Text <= 1000 Then
            Employee2.Add(InputTextbox.Text)
            EmployeeListbox2.DataSource = Nothing
            EmployeeListbox2.DataSource = Employee1
            InputTextbox.Clear()
        End If
    End If
```

This one keeps coming out with an exception unhandled cannot convert string to double?

So don't know what's going on there.

Anyway any suggestions?

Comment: What is the Employee1 variable?, why do you insert into the students always the same textbox? Why do you try to insert a string where a number is expected? The string "1" is not the number 1. See what is _Option Strict_ in VB.NET

Comment: the input textbox is the same, thats why I'm having the issues I have the one input textbox that is used for all three employees and the variable is output as integer

Answer (score 0):

Since you have clarified your question, I have changed the code below and left the old code there in case it helps.

We are using **CurrentListbox** to keep track of which listbox is the current one.

You could just count of how many values are entered and then divide by 7 to see which listbox to populate or the id/name of the listbox itself, we just used a simple number.

The loop below in the button click expects 7 values separated by commas.

If there are less than 7 values, when you next enter values they will start to populate the last listbox starting from beginning again.

If there are more than 7 then nothing will be done with the extra values.

```
Class MyForm

    Dim CurrentListbox as Integer

    Sub Form_Load()
        '
        CurrentListbox = 1
        Listbox1.Items.Clear
        Listbox2.Items.Clear
        Listbox3.Items.Clear
        '
    End Sub

    Sub Button_Click()
        '
        Dim DataArray As String()
        Dim CountA As Integer
        '
        DataArray = Split(Textbox1.Text, ",")
        For CountA = 1 To DataArray.Count 
            If Counta >= 1 And Counter =< 7 Then
                Select Case CurrentListbox
                    Case "Listbox1"
                        ListBox1.Items.Add(DataArray(CountA-1))

                    Case "Listbox2"
                        ListBox2.Items.Add(DataArray(CountA-1))

                    Case "Listbox3"
                        ListBox3.Items.Add(DataArray(CountA-1))

                End Select

            ElseIf CountA = 7 Then
                'change to next listbox if not the last one
                If CurrentListbox < 4 Then
                    CurrentListbox = CurrentListbox + 1
                Else
                    ' last one - no more listboxes
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Textbox1.Text = ""
        '
    End Sub
    '
End Class
```

## OLD ANSWER

You can use the SPLIT function to split the text from the textbox into an array of single values.

each value in your textbox could be separated by a comma (or a space or anything else you want to use as a splitter).

Then you set up a loop through the array of single values adding each one to the listboxes based upon how many values you entered on your textbox.

```
Dim DataArray As String()
Dim CountA As Integer
'
Listbox1.Items.Clear
Listbox2.Items.Clear
Listbox3.Items.Clear
'DataArray = Split("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21", ",")
DataArray = Split(Textbox1.Text, ",")
For CountA = 0 To DataArray.Count - 1
  Select Case CountA

    Case 0 To 6
      ListBox1.Items.Add(DataArray(CountA))

    Case 7 To 13
      ListBox2.Items.Add(DataArray(CountA))

    Case 14 To 20
      ListBox3.Items.Add(DataArray(CountA))

  End Select
Next
```

Comment: Hm, I put this in my code and still doesnt seem to be working, The listbox.clear stuff at the top doesnt work and its also only accepting data in to the first listbox as well

Comment: You would need to change the names of the listboxes to the same names as you use in your app. Like EmployeeListbox1,  EmployeeListbox2, EmployeeListbox3, and InputTextbox too.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add ITEMS so it should be Listbox1.ITEMS.Clear

Comment: Alright well that part did work but it still doesn't move to the second textbox...

Comment: So how many textboxes do you have? I thought there was only one and when you wrote textboxes you meant listboxes because your title states listboxes.

Comment: Ive got one textbox where the user inputs the data and then I've got three listboxes where the data should be displayed. The user will enter the data into the input textbox and it will display in the first employee listbox once there is 7 numbers in the listbox but it should move to the second listbox accepting 7 numbers in there before moving to the third employee

Comment: When you enter your values in the textbox, how many values do you enter each time?  and will you be entering them then clicking the button to load listbox1 and repeating the process for each listbox in turn? or entering all 21 values and then loading them into all the listboxes after clicking the button?

Comment: The user should only be allowed to enter 7 numbers it should be able to enter when the user presses the enter button or the enter key on the keyboard it should enter each number as the user inputs it